# How to add a setTimeout to a hover function?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I found this effect to wait a few seconds before hiding the content.

```js
var timeout;

function hide() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $("#tooltip").hide('fast');
    }, 500);
};

$("#tip").mouseover(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $("#tooltip").stop().show('fast');
}).mouseout(hide);

$("#tooltip").mouseover(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}).mouseout(hide);
```

```css
div { 
    display: none; 
    background-color: 'yellow';
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="tip" href="#">Tooltip</a>
<div id="tooltip">Tootlip contents</div>
```

I was trying to add that functionality to this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myvid").hover(function(){
    // Show our tooltip on hover
    $(".tooltip").show();
  }, function(){
    // Hide our tooltip
    $(".tooltip").hide();
  })
});
```

I did it this way: but it did not work :(

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var timeout;

    fuction hide() {
        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            $("#tooltip").hide('fast');
        }, 500);
    };

  $("#myvid").hover(function(){
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    // Show our tooltip on hover
    //$(".tooltip").show();
    $(".tooltip").stop().show('fast');
  }).hover(hide);
    // Hide our tooltip
  $(".tooltip").hover(function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    $(".tooltip").hide();
  }).hover(hide);
});
```

And this is my code that allows me to show a title by doing `hover` from an`iframe`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myvid").hover(function(){
    // Show our tooltip on hover
    $(".tooltip").show();
  }, function(){
    // Hide our tooltip
    $(".tooltip").hide();
  })
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  height: 40px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.tooltip .title-background {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 40px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.tooltip .title-display {
 color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myvid">
      <div class="tooltip" style="display:none;"><div class="title-background"></div><span class="title-display">Movie Title</span></div>
      <iframe width="420" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
      </iframe>
    </div>
```

How do I correctly add that effect to my jQuery code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very rudimentary, but should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  let hideTimeout;
  $("#myvid").hover(function(){
    // Show our tooltip on hover
    clearTimeout(hideTimeout);
    $(".tooltip").show();
  }, function(){
    // Hide our tooltip
    hideTimeout = setTimeout(()=>{$(".tooltip").hide()}, 2000);
  })
});
```

Also made a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/taL26b3r/2/

However, you could also use CSS to solve this problem, more elegantly perhaps: https://jsfiddle.net/Lmop83g0/

Comment: Glad to help out :D

Answer (score 0):

You have two main problems here.

First, in the example function, they're using `mouseenter` and `mouseout`, but you're using `hover`.

If we look at the [jQuery docs for `hover`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/), we can see that `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);` (like in the example) can be changed to a `hover` function by doing `$(selector).hover(handlerIn, handlerOut);`.

You're trying to chain two `hover` functions together for showing and hiding, but what you really need to do is put two functions inside one `hover`.

Your other problem is simply that your `hide()` function is looking for `#tooltip`, but that element doesn't exist. It should be looking for `.tooltip` instead.

Putting it all together, you should get this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timeout;
  
  function hide() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
      $('.tooltip').hide('fast');
    }, 500);
  };
  
  $('#myvid').hover(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    // Show our tooltip on hover
    $('.tooltip').stop().show('fast');
  }, function() {
    // Hide our tooltip
    hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#myvid {
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
  height: 360px;
}

.tooltip {
  height: 40px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.tooltip .title-background {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 40px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.tooltip .title-display {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 500;
  left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
}

.iframe {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myvid">
  <div class="tooltip" style="display:none;">
    <div class="title-background"></div><span class="title-display">Movie Title</span></div>
    <div class="iframe"></div>
</div>
```

Note that your example function has a separate function for keeping the tooltip from disappearing when you're hovering the tooltip itself, but in your example you don't need that because you're always going to be hovering `#myvid` when you're hovering the tooltip since you've positioned the tooltip on top of `#myvid`. So that second function isn't included in the snippet above.

Comment: I got confused, I commented on so much code, I thought it would be easy to do it on my own, but it was not like that :(